# Able to Locate Element on Selector Hub but Seleniun throwing No Such Element Exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
tcols = drive.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='rowgroup']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]")
```

Able to Locate Element on Selector Hub but Selenium Throwing No Such Element Exception
[https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/viewSystemUsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJMg9.png)

Tried to Find  Text for Column

Comment: try using [Selenium WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)